# Return expression instead result

Tags: c#

If I have function like this

```
double GetExpression(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return x * y + z;
}
```

is it possible to modify it somehow, to not return result immediately only some object which is expression and then evaluate it this way:

```
var expression = GetExpression(1,2,3);
double result = expression.Execute() or expression.Evaluate()
```

other words just return function 
?

Comment: Do you mean return an anonymous function? With or without closures?

Comment: Something to help with your learning, the *delegate*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes!

```
Func<double> GetExpression(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return () => x * y + z;
}
```

use as:

```
var expression = GetExpression(1,2,3);
double result = expression();
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, you could use delegates, and return a `Func<double>`:

```
Func<double> GetExpression(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return () => x * y + z;
}

var expression = GetExpression(1,2,3);
double result = expression(); // Or expression.Invoke()
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Now each time you call `expression()` it will execute the code in the [lambda expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). You can observe that if you use code which doesn't just return the same value each time. For example:

```
Func<int> GetExpression()
{
    Random rng = new Random();
    return () => rng.Next(10);
}

var expression = GetExpression();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(expression());
}
```

That will print 10 random numbers in the range [0, 10). Note that this will only create *one* instance of `Random` (avoiding a [common problem](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx)) - each time you call `expression()` it will call the `Next()` method on the same instance. The constructor for `Random` is called in the "normal" part of the method - it's *not* in the lambda expression. So that gets executed when you first call the `GetExpression` method (even if you never call `expression()` afterwards).

Note however that the arguments to your `GetExpression` were still passed by value though, and are captured by the lambda express. So consider this:

```
Func<int> GetExpression(int a, List<int> b)
{
    return () => a + b.Count;
}

int x = 10;
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var expression = GetExpression(x, list);
Console.WriteLine(expression()); // 13
x = 20;
list.Add(100);
Console.WriteLine(expression()); // 14
```

Here the value of the `list` variable has been captured, so changes the the object that the value refers to *are* visible in the lambda expression, but changes to the `x` variable itself are *not* visible in the lambda expression. (Likewise if you had `list = new List<int>();` that change wouldn't be visible...

Comment: yes thats it , thanks Jon, but I will accept Kobi , he was faster.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think you need to modify your second example to remove the parameters.

Comment: @Kobi: No, it doesn't - which is important in itself. There's *one* instance of `Random` created, and then `Next()` is called on it 10 times.

Comment: I wasn't careful enough. Thanks!

Comment: @Kobi: It's an interesting aspect of the code though, so I've now highlighted it :)

Comment: @JonSkeet something may be up with your last one too, I get "No overload for GetExpression takes 0 parameters" on the `var expression =` line...

Comment: @RonBeyer: Humbug, yes - I was in too much of a hurry :) Fixed.

Comment: Also, `Console.WriteLine(expression);` returns System.Func1[System.Int32] instead of invoking the expression as I believe you intended.

Comment: @Grax: Yes indeed - again, fixed... *Hopefully* that's the lot now!

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Jon Skeet's answer, about capturing variables, if you didn't want to, you could do something like this:

```
double GetExpression(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return x * y + z;
}

Func<int, int, int, double> expression = GetExpression;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", expression(i, i+1, i+2));
```

Which avoids modifying the existing code (in case you wanted to point to a function you didn't have control over), and avoids capturing values outside of the lamda.